# Does one say this prayer for medical procedures on a procedure that gives guidance rather than help?

Tags: halacha, tefilla, health-safety-shmira, shulchan-aruch

Shulchan Aruch (OC 230:4, as explained by Magen Avraham ibid. :6) paskens that when one undergoes a medical procedure he should say the following prayer:

> יהי רצון מלפניך ה׳ אלקי שיהא עסק זה לי לרפואה כי רופא חנם אתה

(See further [here](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/82911/9682) regarding the text of this prayer.)

Does this apply to procedures such as X-rays, CT scans, MRIs, endoscopies, blood tests, and strep tests? On the one hand, they are all medical procedures. On the other hand, they don't inherently perform relief for the patient; they merely give the doctor additional data he or she wouldn't have otherwise, and based on that additional data, other medical treatments, for which the prayer is certainly necessary, would be prescribed. Do any poskim discuss whether such tests, meant for gaining more information rather than providing relief, are included in the above Halacha for which a prayer is necessitated?

Comment: Please check that my edit matches your intent.

Comment: http://parsha.blogspot.com/2007/08/why-i-oppose-refuah-card.html?m=1

Comment: @joshwaxman Do you even hear yourself? Did you really just say you don't like the Magen Avraham and therefore you're just going to ignore him? (Be that as it may, that has nothing to do with this question; Im asking specifically according to the opinions I cited.)

Comment: @DonielF thanks, I hear myself just fine. I never said "I don't like the Magen Avraham." I said "Thus, I would disagree with the Magen Avraham and agree with רד"א." Looking through the sources and agreeing (and then paskening) like one authority as opposed to another is not "ignoring it".